# Elasticity of y w.r.t x when $y^{2}e^{(x+1)/y}=3$

Tags: calculus

OK, so, for this question, I got the answer

$\frac{xy}{y(1+x-2y)}$

Which was achieved by calculating the partial derivative of y w.r.t. x, and then multiplying the term by $x/y$.

However, my textbook seems to suggest that the answer is

$\frac {xy}{1-2y}$

Any suggestions as to what the answer *actually* is? Am I correct or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Product rule.

$\large 2y\frac{dy}{dx} e^\frac{x+1}{y} +y^2e^{\frac{x+1}{y}}\frac{y-\frac{dy}{dx}(x+1)}{y^2}=0$

$\large 2y^3 \frac{dy}{dx}
e^\frac{x+1}{y} + y^2 e^\frac{x+1}{y}(y-\frac{dy}{dx}(x+1))=0$

$\large y^2e^\frac{x+1}{y}(2y\frac{dy}{dx}+y-\frac{dy}{dx}(x+1))=0$

$\large (2y-x-1)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$

$\boxed{\large \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{1+x-2y}}$

Comment: i think this is right, and i checked w wolfram alpha

Comment: fun fact when i was writing this solution i derived the expression inside the exponential itself and it took me like a minute to realize xd